# Set aspect ratio programmatically for imageView

Tags: android, aspect-ratio, android-constraintlayout

I have a problem with showing a landscape image without centerCrop.
I tried `PercentFramelayout`, and set aspect ratio programmatically 
like this:

```
laParams.percentLayoutInfo.aspectRatio = img.width.toFloat() / img.height.toFloat()
```

The result is ok -- the application showed all landscape images without centerCrop:

[image: Post loaded successfully]

But sometimes I get the wrong aspect ratio:

[image: Wrong aspect ratio 1]

[image: Wrong aspect ratio 2]

I tried `android:adjustViewBounds ="true"` but it does not help me.
And I used `ConstraintLayout`, setting the aspect ratio in XML like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,16:9"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I got good result, but I load images different size. Images should be without `CenterCrop` and `FitXY`. I didn't find any good answers about set aspect ratio programmatically for `Constraintlayout`
I want to show images like instagram or vk.

Comment: Hi Muhammadjon if my answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 56):

just changing the layoutParams also works

```
 (view.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams).dimensionRatio = "16:9"
```

Comment: This works. Also can set the "H"/"W" to set only height or width. And can set the value as float instead. Had some issues trying to constrain it, but eventually done with this too

Answer (score 46):

Late answer, as usual, but this might be useful to someone.

You can set the ratio property programatically by doing the following:

```
ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
set.clone(mLayout);
set.setDimensionRatio(mView.getId(), "16:9");
set.applyTo(mLayout);
```

What I am doing above is getting the layout's existing ConstraintSet and adding the ratio constraint programmatically before reapplying the ConstraintSet unto the ConstraintLayout (mLayout).

You should get the ConstraintLayout (mLayout) by using the findViewById() method (and manually adding the id property to your ConstraintLayout in your .xml).

Comment: we can also use:
`set.setDimensionRatio(mLayout.getChildAt(0).getId(), "16:9");`
if you have the child position in the layout

Comment: Which layout id you are passing in mView.getId()?

Comment: @ChintanParmar the id of the view on which you want to apply the aspect ratio

Answer (score 11):

you can also check the below code

```
val layoutParams = imageView.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
layoutParams.dimensionRatio = "H,2:1"
imageView.layoutParams = layoutParams
```

Answer (score -2):

```
val parent = ViewGroup(context)
val view   = View(context)

view.apply {
     id           = View.generateViewId()
     layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0, 0)
}

parent.apply {
     id = View.generateViewId()
     removeAllViews()
     addView(rootViewGroup)
}

ConstraintSet().apply {
     clone(parent)

     val viewId   = rootViewGroup.id
     val parentId = parent.id

        connect(viewId, START,  parentId, START)
        connect(viewId, END,    parentId, END)
        connect(viewId, TOP,    parentId, TOP)
        connect(viewId, BOTTOM, parentId, BOTTOM)

        setDimensionRatio(rootId, "1:1")

        applyTo(parent)
}
```