# Keep Aspect Ratio Exoplayer without using com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView

Tags: android, opengl-es, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am currently working on an OpenGL demo project of exoplayer version "2.12.1".

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/r2.12.1/demos/gl

MainActivity.java

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2020 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.google.android.exoplayer2.gldemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.C;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaItem;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSessionManager;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DrmSessionManager;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.FrameworkMediaDrm;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.HttpMediaDrmCallback;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.dash.DashMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Assertions;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.EventLogger;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.GlUtil;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Activity that demonstrates playback of video to an {@link android.opengl.GLSurfaceView} with
 * postprocessing of the video content using GL.
 */
public final class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

  private static final String DEFAULT_MEDIA_URI =
      "https://storage.googleapis.com/exoplayer-test-media-1/mkv/android-screens-lavf-56.36.100-aac-avc-main-1280x720.mkv";

  private static final String ACTION_VIEW = "com.google.android.exoplayer.gldemo.action.VIEW";
  private static final String EXTENSION_EXTRA = "extension";
  private static final String DRM_SCHEME_EXTRA = "drm_scheme";
  private static final String DRM_LICENSE_URL_EXTRA = "drm_license_url";

  @Nullable private PlayerView playerView;
  @Nullable private VideoProcessingGLSurfaceView videoProcessingGLSurfaceView;

  @Nullable private SimpleExoPlayer player;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    boolean requestSecureSurface = getIntent().hasExtra(DRM_SCHEME_EXTRA);
    if (requestSecureSurface && !GlUtil.isProtectedContentExtensionSupported(context)) {
      Toast.makeText(
              context, R.string.error_protected_content_extension_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
          .show();
    }

    VideoProcessingGLSurfaceView videoProcessingGLSurfaceView =
        new VideoProcessingGLSurfaceView(
            context, requestSecureSurface, new BitmapOverlayVideoProcessor(context));
    FrameLayout contentFrame = findViewById(R.id.exo_content_frame);
    contentFrame.addView(videoProcessingGLSurfaceView);
    this.videoProcessingGLSurfaceView = videoProcessingGLSurfaceView;
  }

  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (Util.SDK_INT > 23) {
      initializePlayer();
      if (playerView != null) {
        playerView.onResume();
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (Util.SDK_INT <= 23 || player == null) {
      initializePlayer();
      if (playerView != null) {
        playerView.onResume();
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (Util.SDK_INT <= 23) {
      if (playerView != null) {
        playerView.onPause();
      }
      releasePlayer();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (Util.SDK_INT > 23) {
      if (playerView != null) {
        playerView.onPause();
      }
      releasePlayer();
    }
  }

  private void initializePlayer() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Uri uri =
        ACTION_VIEW.equals(action)
            ? Assertions.checkNotNull(intent.getData())
            : Uri.parse(DEFAULT_MEDIA_URI);
    DrmSessionManager drmSessionManager;
    if (Util.SDK_INT >= 18 && intent.hasExtra(DRM_SCHEME_EXTRA)) {
      String drmScheme = Assertions.checkNotNull(intent.getStringExtra(DRM_SCHEME_EXTRA));
      String drmLicenseUrl = Assertions.checkNotNull(intent.getStringExtra(DRM_LICENSE_URL_EXTRA));
      UUID drmSchemeUuid = Assertions.checkNotNull(Util.getDrmUuid(drmScheme));
      HttpDataSource.Factory licenseDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory();
      HttpMediaDrmCallback drmCallback =
          new HttpMediaDrmCallback(drmLicenseUrl, licenseDataSourceFactory);
      drmSessionManager =
          new DefaultDrmSessionManager.Builder()
              .setUuidAndExoMediaDrmProvider(drmSchemeUuid, FrameworkMediaDrm.DEFAULT_PROVIDER)
              .build(drmCallback);
    } else {
      drmSessionManager = DrmSessionManager.getDummyDrmSessionManager();
    }

    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this);
    MediaSource mediaSource;
    @C.ContentType int type = Util.inferContentType(uri, intent.getStringExtra(EXTENSION_EXTRA));
    if (type == C.TYPE_DASH) {
      mediaSource =
          new DashMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
              .setDrmSessionManager(drmSessionManager)
              .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(uri));
    } else if (type == C.TYPE_OTHER) {
      mediaSource =
          new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
              .setDrmSessionManager(drmSessionManager)
              .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(uri));
    } else {
      throw new IllegalStateException();
    }

    SimpleExoPlayer player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
    player.setRepeatMode(Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL);
    player.setMediaSource(mediaSource);
    player.prepare();
    player.play();
    VideoProcessingGLSurfaceView videoProcessingGLSurfaceView =
        Assertions.checkNotNull(this.videoProcessingGLSurfaceView);
    videoProcessingGLSurfaceView.setVideoComponent(
        Assertions.checkNotNull(player.getVideoComponent()));
    Assertions.checkNotNull(playerView).setPlayer(player);
    player.addAnalyticsListener(new EventLogger(/* trackSelector= */ null));
    this.player = player;
  }

  private void releasePlayer() {
    Assertions.checkNotNull(playerView).setPlayer(null);
    if (player != null) {
      player.release();
      Assertions.checkNotNull(videoProcessingGLSurfaceView).setVideoComponent(null);
      player = null;
    }
  }
}
```

BitmapOverlayVideoProcessor.java

```
package com.google.android.exoplayer2.gldemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.C;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Assertions;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.GlUtil;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

/**
 * Video processor that demonstrates how to overlay a bitmap on video output using a GL shader. The
 * bitmap is drawn using an Android {@link Canvas}.
 */
/* package */ final class BitmapOverlayVideoProcessor
    implements VideoProcessingGLSurfaceView.VideoProcessor {

  private static final int OVERLAY_WIDTH = 512;
  private static final int OVERLAY_HEIGHT = 256;

  private final Context context;
  private final Paint paint;
  private final int[] textures;
  private final Bitmap overlayBitmap;
  private final Bitmap logoBitmap;
  private final Canvas overlayCanvas;

  private int program;
  @Nullable private GlUtil.Attribute[] attributes;
  @Nullable private GlUtil.Uniform[] uniforms;

  private float bitmapScaleX;
  private float bitmapScaleY;

  public BitmapOverlayVideoProcessor(Context context) {
    this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextSize(64);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setARGB(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    textures = new int[1];
    overlayBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(OVERLAY_WIDTH, OVERLAY_HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    overlayCanvas = new Canvas(overlayBitmap);
    try {
      logoBitmap =
          ((BitmapDrawable)
                  context.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(context.getPackageName()))
              .getBitmap();
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void initialize() {
    String vertexShaderCode =
        loadAssetAsString(context, "bitmap_overlay_video_processor_vertex.glsl");
    String fragmentShaderCode =
        loadAssetAsString(context, "bitmap_overlay_video_processor_fragment.glsl");
    program = GlUtil.compileProgram(vertexShaderCode, fragmentShaderCode);
    GlUtil.Attribute[] attributes = GlUtil.getAttributes(program);
    GlUtil.Uniform[] uniforms = GlUtil.getUniforms(program);
    for (GlUtil.Attribute attribute : attributes) {
      if (attribute.name.equals("a_position")) {
        attribute.setBuffer(new float[] {-1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1}, 2);
      } else if (attribute.name.equals("a_texcoord")) {
        attribute.setBuffer(new float[] {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 2);
      }
    }
    this.attributes = attributes;
    this.uniforms = uniforms;
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, /* level= */ 0, overlayBitmap, /* border= */ 0);
  }

  @Override
  public void setSurfaceSize(int width, int height) {
    bitmapScaleX = (float) width / OVERLAY_WIDTH;
    bitmapScaleY = (float) height / OVERLAY_HEIGHT;
  }

  @Override
  public void draw(int frameTexture, long frameTimestampUs) {
    // Draw to the canvas and store it in a texture.
    String text = String.format(Locale.US, "%.02f", frameTimestampUs / (float) C.MICROS_PER_SECOND);
    overlayBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    overlayCanvas.drawBitmap(logoBitmap, /* left= */ 32, /* top= */ 32, paint);
    overlayCanvas.drawText(text, /* x= */ 200, /* y= */ 130, paint);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    GLUtils.texSubImage2D(
        GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, /* level= */ 0, /* xoffset= */ 0, /* yoffset= */ 0, overlayBitmap);
    GlUtil.checkGlError();

    // Run the shader program.
    GlUtil.Uniform[] uniforms = Assertions.checkNotNull(this.uniforms);
    GlUtil.Attribute[] attributes = Assertions.checkNotNull(this.attributes);
    GLES20.glUseProgram(program);
    for (GlUtil.Uniform uniform : uniforms) {
      switch (uniform.name) {
        case "tex_sampler_0":
          uniform.setSamplerTexId(frameTexture, /* unit= */ 0);
          break;
        case "tex_sampler_1":
          uniform.setSamplerTexId(textures[0], /* unit= */ 1);
          break;
        case "scaleX":
          uniform.setFloat(bitmapScaleX);
          break;
        case "scaleY":
          uniform.setFloat(bitmapScaleY);
          break;
      }
    }
    for (GlUtil.Attribute copyExternalAttribute : attributes) {
      copyExternalAttribute.bind();
    }
    for (GlUtil.Uniform copyExternalUniform : uniforms) {
      copyExternalUniform.bind();
    }
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, /* first= */ 0, /* count= */ 4);
    GlUtil.checkGlError();
  }

  private static String loadAssetAsString(Context context, String assetFileName) {
    @Nullable InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
      inputStream = context.getAssets().open(assetFileName);
      return Util.fromUtf8Bytes(Util.toByteArray(inputStream));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    } finally {
      Util.closeQuietly(inputStream);
    }
  }
}
```

VideoProcessingGLSurfaceView.java

```
package com.google.android.exoplayer2.gldemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.media.MediaFormat;
import android.opengl.EGL14;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Surface;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Format;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Assertions;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.GlUtil;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.TimedValueQueue;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.VideoFrameMetadataListener;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGL10;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLContext;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLDisplay;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLSurface;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

/**
 * {@link GLSurfaceView} that creates a GL context (optionally for protected content) and passes
 * video frames to a {@link VideoProcessor} for drawing to the view.
 *
 * <p>This view must be created programmatically, as it is necessary to specify whether a context
 * supporting protected content should be created at construction time.
 */
public final class VideoProcessingGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

  /** Processes video frames, provided via a GL texture. */
  public interface VideoProcessor {
    /** Performs any required GL initialization. */
    void initialize();

    /** Sets the size of the output surface in pixels. */
    void setSurfaceSize(int width, int height);

    /**
     * Draws using GL operations.
     *
     * @param frameTexture The ID of a GL texture containing a video frame.
     * @param frameTimestampUs The presentation timestamp of the frame, in microseconds.
     */
    void draw(int frameTexture, long frameTimestampUs);
  }

  private static final int EGL_PROTECTED_CONTENT_EXT = 0x32C0;

  private final VideoRenderer renderer;
  private final Handler mainHandler;

  @Nullable private SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture;
  @Nullable private Surface surface;
  @Nullable private Player.VideoComponent videoComponent;

  /**
   * Creates a new instance. Pass {@code true} for {@code requireSecureContext} if the {@link
   * GLSurfaceView GLSurfaceView's} associated GL context should handle secure content (if the
   * device supports it).
   *
   * @param context The {@link Context}.
   * @param requireSecureContext Whether a GL context supporting protected content should be
   *     created, if supported by the device.
   * @param videoProcessor Processor that draws to the view.
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("InlinedApi")
  public VideoProcessingGLSurfaceView(
      Context context, boolean requireSecureContext, VideoProcessor videoProcessor) {
    super(context);
    renderer = new VideoRenderer(videoProcessor);
    mainHandler = new Handler();
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    setEGLConfigChooser(
        /* redSize= */ 8,
        /* greenSize= */ 8,
        /* blueSize= */ 8,
        /* alphaSize= */ 8,
        /* depthSize= */ 0,
        /* stencilSize= */ 0);
    setEGLContextFactory(
        new EGLContextFactory() {
          @Override
          public EGLContext createContext(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
            int[] glAttributes;
            if (requireSecureContext) {
              glAttributes =
                  new int[] {
                    EGL14.EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION,
                    2,
                    EGL_PROTECTED_CONTENT_EXT,
                    EGL14.EGL_TRUE,
                    EGL14.EGL_NONE
                  };
            } else {
              glAttributes = new int[] {EGL14.EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL14.EGL_NONE};
            }
            return egl.eglCreateContext(
                display, eglConfig, /* share_context= */ EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, glAttributes);
          }

          @Override
          public void destroyContext(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display, EGLContext context) {
            egl.eglDestroyContext(display, context);
          }
        });
    setEGLWindowSurfaceFactory(
        new EGLWindowSurfaceFactory() {
          @Override
          public EGLSurface createWindowSurface(
              EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display, EGLConfig config, Object nativeWindow) {
            int[] attribsList =
                requireSecureContext
                    ? new int[] {EGL_PROTECTED_CONTENT_EXT, EGL14.EGL_TRUE, EGL10.EGL_NONE}
                    : new int[] {EGL10.EGL_NONE};
            return egl.eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, nativeWindow, attribsList);
          }

          @Override
          public void destroySurface(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display, EGLSurface surface) {
            egl.eglDestroySurface(display, surface);
          }
        });
    setRenderer(renderer);
    setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
  }

  /**
   * Attaches or detaches (if {@code newVideoComponent} is {@code null}) this view from the video
   * component of the player.
   *
   * @param newVideoComponent The new video component, or {@code null} to detach this view.
   */
  public void setVideoComponent(@Nullable Player.VideoComponent newVideoComponent) {
    if (newVideoComponent == videoComponent) {
      return;
    }
    if (videoComponent != null) {
      if (surface != null) {
        videoComponent.clearVideoSurface(surface);
      }
      videoComponent.clearVideoFrameMetadataListener(renderer);
    }
    videoComponent = newVideoComponent;
    if (videoComponent != null) {
      videoComponent.setVideoFrameMetadataListener(renderer);
      videoComponent.setVideoSurface(surface);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    // Post to make sure we occur in order with any onSurfaceTextureAvailable calls.
    mainHandler.post(
        () -> {
          if (surface != null) {
            if (videoComponent != null) {
              videoComponent.setVideoSurface(null);
            }
            releaseSurface(surfaceTexture, surface);
            surfaceTexture = null;
            surface = null;
          }
        });
  }

  private void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
    mainHandler.post(
        () -> {
          SurfaceTexture oldSurfaceTexture = this.surfaceTexture;
          Surface oldSurface = VideoProcessingGLSurfaceView.this.surface;
          this.surfaceTexture = surfaceTexture;
          this.surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
          releaseSurface(oldSurfaceTexture, oldSurface);
          if (videoComponent != null) {
            videoComponent.setVideoSurface(surface);
          }
        });
  }

  private static void releaseSurface(
      @Nullable SurfaceTexture oldSurfaceTexture, @Nullable Surface oldSurface) {
    if (oldSurfaceTexture != null) {
      oldSurfaceTexture.release();
    }
    if (oldSurface != null) {
      oldSurface.release();
    }
  }

  private final class VideoRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer, VideoFrameMetadataListener {

    private final VideoProcessor videoProcessor;
    private final AtomicBoolean frameAvailable;
    private final TimedValueQueue<Long> sampleTimestampQueue;

    private int texture;
    @Nullable private SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture;

    private boolean initialized;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private long frameTimestampUs;

    public VideoRenderer(VideoProcessor videoProcessor) {
      this.videoProcessor = videoProcessor;
      frameAvailable = new AtomicBoolean();
      sampleTimestampQueue = new TimedValueQueue<>();
      width = -1;
      height = -1;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
      texture = GlUtil.createExternalTexture();
      surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(texture);
      surfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(
          surfaceTexture -> {
            frameAvailable.set(true);
            requestRender();
          });
      onSurfaceTextureAvailable(surfaceTexture);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
      GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
      if (videoProcessor == null) {
        return;
      }

      if (!initialized) {
        videoProcessor.initialize();
        initialized = true;
      }

      if (width != -1 && height != -1) {
        videoProcessor.setSurfaceSize(width, height);
        width = -1;
        height = -1;
      }

      if (frameAvailable.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
        SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = Assertions.checkNotNull(this.surfaceTexture);
        surfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
        long lastFrameTimestampNs = surfaceTexture.getTimestamp();
        Long frameTimestampUs = sampleTimestampQueue.poll(lastFrameTimestampNs);
        if (frameTimestampUs != null) {
          this.frameTimestampUs = frameTimestampUs;
        }
      }

      videoProcessor.draw(texture, frameTimestampUs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoFrameAboutToBeRendered(
        long presentationTimeUs,
        long releaseTimeNs,
        @NonNull Format format,
        @Nullable MediaFormat mediaFormat) {
      sampleTimestampQueue.add(releaseTimeNs, presentationTimeUs);
    }
  }
}
```

bitmap_overlay_video_processor_vertex.glsl

```
attribute vec2 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texcoord;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
void main() {
 gl_Position = vec4(a_position.x, a_position.y, 0, 1);
 v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
}
```

bitmap_overlay_video_processor_fragment.glsl

```
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
precision mediump float;
// External texture containing video decoder output.
uniform samplerExternalOES tex_sampler_0;
// Texture containing the overlap bitmap.
uniform sampler2D tex_sampler_1;
// Horizontal scaling factor for the overlap bitmap.
uniform float scaleX;
// Vertical scaling factory for the overlap bitmap.
uniform float scaleY;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
void main() {
  vec4 videoColor = texture2D(tex_sampler_0, v_texcoord);
  vec4 overlayColor = texture2D(tex_sampler_1,
                                vec2(v_texcoord.x * scaleX,
                                     v_texcoord.y * scaleY));
  // Blend the video decoder output and the overlay bitmap.
  gl_FragColor = videoColor * (1.0 - overlayColor.a)
      + overlayColor * overlayColor.a;
}
```

For my application I cannot use   `com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView`.
But if i did not called `Assertions.checkNotNull(playerView).setPlayer(player);` , then the video will not keep it's aspect ratio.

***So How can I programmatically correct the aspect ratio of the video by manipulating Shader code instead of PlayerView?***

Comment: @Rabbid76  Question Updated :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using xml, you can add your playerview to contraint layout

and then add attribute

```
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
```

inside the xml declaration of playerview, for example I am using styledplayerview with

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView
    android:id="@+id/home_exoplayer_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />
```

### Edit: This attribute doesn't depend on the version of Exoplayer.

For your purpose you have two options to keep aspect ratio constant, regardless of screen size or video dimentions.

1)Either change the Frame layout to Contraint layout and use "app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio" attribute inside your player view.

Example code for your purpose to replace frame layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2020 The Android Open Source Project
     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at
          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:keepScreenOn="true">

  <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
    android:id="@+id/player_view"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:surface_type="none"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Another workaround can be nesting constraint layout inside the frame layout.

Like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2020 The Android Open Source Project
     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at
          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:keepScreenOn="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
      <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/player_view"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:surface_type="none"/>
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

---

### Programmatically

Also you can achieve the same results using

```
(view.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams).dimensionRatio = "16:9"
```

or

```
val layoutParams = imageView.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
layoutParams.dimensionRatio = "H,2:1"
imageView.layoutParams = layoutParams
```

[As shown in these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52954098/13252809)

Comment: Question is about exoplayer version "2.12.1".

Comment: @Lins Louis Also, if you can't use this approach of defining ratio through XML, you can do it programmatically by updated answer using as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52954098/13252809

Comment: @Lins Louis Checkout latest answer, it works for me.

Comment: Appreciated your efforts, I know this will work, But Please read last line of my question "So How can I programmatically correct the aspect ratio of the video by manipulating Shader code instead of PlayerView?". I am trying to do it in Opengl Side because for my project i am dealing with multiple video textures so cannot use a common  aspect ratio.I need individual aspect ratio for each video textures.

Answer (score -1):

Didn't noticed that last comment, I see your setup is wrong instead of this

```
SimpleExoPlayer player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
player.setRepeatMode(Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL);
player.setMediaSource(mediaSource);
player.prepare();
player.play();
VideoProcessingGLSurfaceView videoProcessingGLSurfaceView =
    Assertions.checkNotNull(this.videoProcessingGLSurfaceView);
videoProcessingGLSurfaceView.setVideoComponent(
    Assertions.checkNotNull(player.getVideoComponent()));
Assertions.checkNotNull(playerView).setPlayer(player);
player.addAnalyticsListener(new EventLogger(/* trackSelector= */ null));
this.player = player;
```

Try this:

```
this.player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
player.setRepeatMode(Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL);
player.setMediaSource(mediaSource);
Assertions.checkNotNull(playerView).setPlayer(player); // this needs to happen once during your setup 
player.playWhenReady = true // this is recommended by official docs instead of player.play() always call it before prepare
player.prepare();
VideoProcessingGLSurfaceView videoProcessingGLSurfaceView =
    Assertions.checkNotNull(this.videoProcessingGLSurfaceView);
videoProcessingGLSurfaceView.setVideoComponent(
    Assertions.checkNotNull(player.getVideoComponent()));
player.addAnalyticsListener(new EventLogger(/* trackSelector= */ null));
```

Comment: Read last line of my question "For my application I cannot use com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView. But if i did not called Assertions.checkNotNull(playerView).setPlayer(player); , then the video will not keep it's aspect ratio.So How can I programmatically correct the aspect ratio of the video by manipulating Shader code instead of PlayerView?"

Comment: Apologies for that I didn't read well, have you tried using a view called <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout> ?